# Is "deployer" a reserved username in Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat

I just found a curious situation with Apache Tomcat.

When I tried to deploy my web application to tomcat via maven. I found that username `deployer` doesn't work yet username `deploy` works.

Is the username `deployer` is a reserved one or somethin'?

```
<role rolename="manager-jmx"/>
<role rolename="manager-script"/>

<!-- doesn't work -->
<user username="deployer" password="some" roles="manager-jmx,manager-script"/>

<!-- works -->
<user username="deploy" password="some" roles="manager-jmx,manager-script"/>
```

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/189912

Comment: @MichaelHampton Voted Up!